# How to optimize color reduction and dithering

Tags: unity-game-engine, hlsl, fragment-shader

I have the following function inside fragment shader, but it reduces fps by 7

```
half3 ClusterAndDithering(half3 color, half2 uv)
{
    half2 clusters = half2(16, 16);
    
    color.xyz = RgbToHsv(color.xyz);
    color.yz = round(color.yz * clusters);

    half2 centerUV = half2(0, 0);
    centerUV.x = floor(uv.x * _BaseMap_TexelSize.z) / _BaseMap_TexelSize.z;
    centerUV.y = ceil(uv.y * _BaseMap_TexelSize.w) / _BaseMap_TexelSize.w;
    half2 UVDither = fmod(centerUV, _BaseMap_TexelSize.xy * 2) * _BaseMap_TexelSize.zw;
    half Min = min(UVDither.x, UVDither.y);
    half Odd = 1 - fmod(color.z, 2);
    half Val = color.z > clusters / 2 ? 0 : 1;
    half Dither = Min * Odd * Val;
    color.z = (color.z + Dither);
    color.yz /= clusters;
    color = HsvToRgb(color);
    return color;
}
```

This code reduces SV chanel variant and making dithering (making grid from center of UV).
For example here's Min value result:
[image]
Odd:
[image]
Val:
[image]
No clustering or dithering:
[image]
Dithering and clustering:
[image]
Any ideas how to optimize it?

Upd:
Changed code a bit (it didn't help, but looks better).

```
half3 ClusterAndDithering(half3 color, half2 uv)
{
    half2 clusters = half2(8,8);
        
    color.xyz = RgbToHsv(color.xyz);
    color.yz = round(color.yz * clusters);
    
    half2 centerUV = half2(0, 0);
    centerUV.x = floor(uv.x * _BaseMap_TexelSize.z);
    centerUV.y = ceil(uv.y * _BaseMap_TexelSize.w);
    centerUV = fmod(centerUV, 2);
    half Min = min(centerUV.x, centerUV.y);
    half Odd = 1 - fmod(color.z, 2);
    half Val = color.z > clusters.y / 2 ? 0 : 1;
    half Dither = Min * Odd * Val;
    color.z = (color.z + Dither);
    color.yz /= clusters;
    color = HsvToRgb(color);
    return color;
}
```

Usage inside fragment function:

```
half4 LitPassFragment(Varyings input) : SV_Target
{
    UNITY_SETUP_INSTANCE_ID(input);
    UNITY_SETUP_STEREO_EYE_INDEX_POST_VERTEX(input);

    SurfaceData surfaceData;
    InitializeStandardLitSurfaceData(input.uv, surfaceData);

    InputData inputData;
    InitializeInputData(input, surfaceData.normalTS, inputData);

    half4 color = UniversalFragmentPBR(inputData, surfaceData.albedo, surfaceData.metallic, surfaceData.specular, surfaceData.smoothness, surfaceData.occlusion, surfaceData.emission, surfaceData.alpha);
    color.rgb = ClusterAndDithering(color.rgb, input.uv);
    color.rgb = MixFog(color.rgb, inputData.fogCoord);
    return color;
}
```

Comment: I know its going to completely ruin the output but how much fps would you gain if you were to remove the `RgbToHsv` and `HsvToRgb`? I'm curious how much those cost, because the rest of it does not seem to me particularly expensive since you aren't doing any sampling or anything...

Comment: I don't see any performance heavy code here. Maybe share your full shader, and are you even sure that the shader is the culprit?

Comment: I found that most weighted functions is calculating Min and converting to HSV

Comment: HSV takes about 2-3 fps, Min function takes about 2 fps.

Comment: I'd rather worry about the 14ms you already have without these than about the 2ms caused by it ^^

Comment: I'm using texel shading, and my card is gt 730. So we can get a little worried about that 2 ms.

Comment: Here's the best HSV to RGB and vice versa conversion I saw
https://web.archive.org/web/20200207113336/http://lolengine.net/blog/2013/07/27/rgb-to-hsv-in-glsl

Answer (score 1):

Finally found custom [function](http://www.chilliant.com/rgb2hsv.html) to convert RGB to HSV and vice versa. It's faster than Unity's built-in. There's no another ways to optimize that code, at least you know how to multiply round and divide value with one function.